# Cross platform GUI window in C++

Tags: c++, window, cross-platform

I wondered why I couldn't find a question about that already. How can I create a cross-platform window in C++? By cross-platform I mean support for at least Windows, Mac and Linux.

If there is a library for only this task out there I am willing to use that. But I don't want to use a bloated library with window controls like *wxWidgets*.

I don't need GUI controls because I am going to use OpenGL. (And for some reason I don't want to use frameworks like *GLUT* or *GLFW*.)

Comment: how do you define *bloated*?

Comment: Are you really sure you didn't get [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/138831/1044750) automatically ?

Comment: I do not need GUI elements but just a window. So in this case a not bloated library would only perform the task of creating and managing (resize, minimize, toggle fullscreen) the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try C++ bindings library for [Tk](http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/).  It's a very lightweight and simple.

Answer (score 3):

There are others, I recommend and use FLTK. But Qt is also my favorite. See what works best for you and your patterns of thinking.

FLTK is extremely light weight.

Comment: I would like to just create a window. Both libraries you mentioned also provide GUI elements. So maybe this is a simpler task can easily be done without a framework, but I am not sure.

Comment: no, I really suggest you stick to 1 cross platform framework. Instantiation of a window in Win32 is fairly different from GTK and that much more different than instantiating on Mac OS X(cocoa).

Comment: Using a cross platform library allows you to abstract away from the native toolkit library(and the fuss in creating them for each platform). You can render OpenGL graphics on a FLTK window(there are _examples_ for that on their website)

Comment: Maybe I will use only the related code from open source cross platform libraries.