# Open source and cross platform application

Tags: matlab, open-source, cross-platform

I would like to know what would be the best programming languages to develop an open source that can work on mainly windows and mac.

any person should be able to change the source code if he/she wanted to without the need to recompile it. this is to allow further development and bug fixing.

The application does not require a massive computational resources and it would have a GUI.

what would you recommend?

the only thing i have in mind is to do the application using matLab. any other choice?

Many thanks for your feedback,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a cross-platform program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138831/how-to-write-a-cross-platform-program) (and some others in the Related sidebar)

Comment: Matlab!?! I don't think "open source" means what you think it means :-) Don't get me wrong, I love Matlab, but it most definitely is NOT open source. Also, I throw my support 100% behind @JesseB (+1). From your description, IMHO Python is the obvious choice. Octave IS the open source version of Matlab, but if you're messing around with GUI's, Python is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python. There are many IDEs available, and the code is extremely readable. The community also maintains excellent documentation. I would advise against using Matlab to develop Open Source Software because Matlab itself is not an open source program. Maybe since you are talking about something mathematical, an open source alternative could be Octave? But I don’t really know what you mean by an application. Hope anything I suggested helped.

Comment: The reason I have considered MatLab, even though MatLab itself is not an open source, is that the application(software) source code is readable and does not require you to recompile it every time you modify it. Moreover, the application is going to be used mainly by university students as a supporting tool for a specific research. I never considered Python, I will look into that. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Hey, and if you choose to go down that road, here is a page that will give you many avenues to jog down: http://scientificpython.tumblr.com/ [disclaimer: this page was lifted from a scientific python 1-day class I took over the summer at my uni]